# Convert Regex pattern to sql

Tags: java, sql, regex, request

I have a SQL database that contains a table of emails.
I would like to select all the emails that have characters from the regex pattern:

```
^[^ @]+@([^ @.]+\\.)+[^ @.]+$
```

I'm trying to write the request but I have mistakes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your actual _database_?  E.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?  We need to know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all this is the solution that worked for me:

WHERE email !~ '^[^ @]+@([^ @.]+.)+[^ @.]+$'

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression for the pattern you are specifying.  You can use `like`:

```
where email like '%@%.%' and
      email not like '%@%@%' and    -- only one @
      email not like '%.%.%' and    -- only one .
      email not like '% %'          -- no space
```

The use of regular expressions depends on the database you are using (but `like` is SQL so it should work in all databases).  Of course, if your (unspecified) database supports regular expression, you can still use them.  If you do so, however, you might do some research because there are better regular expressions for email matching.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example to use RegEx in SQL query

```
SELECT * from table WHERE email REGEXP '^[^ @]+@([^ @.]+\.)+[^ @.]+$';
```

Let me know it works.